# 2つのストレージをRAID0で1つにした後、パーティションを2つに分割するのは有用か？

Tags: aws, raid

RAID0で2つのストレージを一つにしましたが、これをパーティションで2つにするのは有効的ですか？

15GB 15GB をRAID0で30GBにしたのを、25GB 5GB という感じで5GBはスワップにしたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOPSやスループットを管理されたストレージを２つ用意したところで、パフォーマンスは半減するだけです。RAID0管理のためのオーバーヘッド分遅くなるだけかと思われます。

---

suzukisさんが言及されているように、EBSボリューム２つでRAID0構成することでパフォーマンスは倍増します。ただし、EC2インスタンス側の制限を超えることはできません。

[EBSボリューム単体性能](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html)（io1）： 64,000IOPS、スループット 1,000MB/秒
[EC2インスタンス上限](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html)（m5.16xlarge）： 60,000IOPS、スループット 1,250MB/秒

という状況で、相当大きなEC2インスタンスでなければEBSボリュームの性能を出しきれません。

Answer (score 1):

RAID構成したストレージを論理的に分割するのは一般的な手法です。

質問の例であれば要求されるのが性能または単一ドライブで達成できない容量であれば、有効です。

AWSでも(マニュアルを信じれば)同様です

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/raid-config.html